# Check if another process is being killed

Tags: c#, process, exit, kill

I have a process id and I need to check if process is killed or has already received 'kill signal' (from task manager or command prompt etc.). I can check an already exited process simply by checking with `Process.GetProcessById(processId)`. But how to check if the process has already received 'kill signal', i.e., to say, it is due to be killed in next few moments?

Comment: Whatever you do, keep in mind that process IDs are recycled. That is, even your `Process.GetProcessById(processId)` might give you false positives. You need to included more information, like the module/file name and the start time of the process.

Comment: If you want to check if Process has exited you can use `Process.HasExited`

Comment: Mind that you will need UIAccess= true to check on other processes exit